# ASP .NET Core How to get userId value using the primary key value?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to make a verification for a application where, I need to check if the file belong to the user who made the request. If it doesn't the user will receive a **NotFound** response.

I am trying to get the string value of **userId** who owns that file using the **primary key** value and compare to the value of the **userId** who made the request.

The problem is that even the user who owns the file receive **NotFound** response.

I think i don't properly get the value of **user2** string.
How can i fix this?

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<File> GetShare(int id)
        {

            string userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserID").Value;
            string user2 = _context.File.Where(t => t.FileId == id).Select(t => new File()
            {
                UserId = t.UserId

            }).ToString();

            if (userId != user2)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                return _context.File.SingleOrDefault(t => t.FileId == id);
            }
        }
```

The database table is made based on this model:

```
public class File
    {
        [Key]
        public int FileId { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(30)")]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public string Syntax { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(1)]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
        public string Tags { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select code is wrong.

When you do

```
string user2 = _context.File
                       .Where(t => t.FileId == id)
                       .Select(t => new File() { UserId = t.UserId })
                       .ToString();
```

You are basically returning an `IQueryable<File>` and calling a `ToString()` on that which returns some unexpected results, and that string is nowhere close to the userid.

The one possible solution will be

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<File> GetShare(int id)
{
    string userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserID").Value;
    var file = _context.File.FirstOrDefault(t => t.FileId == id);

    if(file == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (userId != file.UserId)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    
    return file;
}
```